# Repeated lyric in Guz & Tough Love - "Dancin' Kinda Close"

Tags: lyrics, electronic-music, house

Guz & Tough Love's song ["Dancin' Kinda Close"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgtGRi_apsk) has a repeated lyric

> ??? little step ??? dancin' kinda close

What is the full lyric with the omitted words?  I haven't been able to find it anywhere.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain what is wrong with the question?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but we usually want to see questions that have full descriptions, not just links.  Links are not searchable, and if they go bad, the question becomes worthless.  I have edited to address these concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either a sample or a resung lyric from R&B group Next's salacious 90's hit ["Too Close,"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oee2t4NROj8) about a young man who is *way* too excited to get on the dance floor.

The sampled part of the lyric is in bold below:

> **Step back, you're dancin' kinda close
>
>   I feel a little** poke comin' through on you

What makes it a bit harder to understand is that the sample is looped so that it sounds more like:

> I feel a little step
>   back you're dancin' kinda close